# command failed when installing package 'hevea'

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, package

when I run pip install hevea I get

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kri1uw9c\hevea\ and same for others packages .

Collecting hevea
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d3/f8/aac0236675222c8af1a005efaf1855b286995b34e362db1ef38742960a62/hevea-0.2.tar.gz

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\testbug\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\hevea\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\hevea\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\hevea\pip-egg-info'
     cwd: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\hevea\
Complete output (7 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\hevea\setup.py", line 21, in <module>
    license=open('LICENSE').read(),
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 181: character maps to <undefined>
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Looking for a solution,
 Thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the file `LICENSE`: [the file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yurimalheiros/hevea/26cf53219720acc60ee62346c566346e43785096/LICENSE) contains a few non-ascii characters (`©`, `“`, `”`) but [it's open with default encoding](https://github.com/yurimalheiros/hevea/blob/26cf53219720acc60ee62346c566346e43785096/setup.py#L12) which prevents it to be open in your environment.

Consider also that the latest release is version 0.2 and [was released at Jan 5, 2013](https://pypi.org/project/hevea/0.2/#files). The package is too old and abandoned. Most probably it requires Python 2.

My advice is to forget it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer .. I will try with another one like  plastex, if you have any idea about what is the pratical one ^^